# Communication failure while joining agent platform: No ICP active - JADE

Tags: java, jade

Olá poderiam me ajudar com isso, estou iniciando agora em JADE, e estou tentando iniciar dois agentes, no entanto dá a seguinte exceção:

```
Communication failure while joining agent platform: No ICP active
jade.core.IMTPException: No ICP active
    at jade.imtp.leap.LEAPIMTPManager.initialize(LEAPIMTPManager.java:138)
    at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.init(AgentContainerImpl.java:320)
    at jade.core.AgentContainerImpl.joinPlatform(AgentContainerImpl.java:494)
    at jade.core.Runtime.createMainContainer(Runtime.java:159)
    at jade.Boot.main(Boot.java:89)
```

A configuração de execução está da seguinte forma: 
**Classe Principal:**

```
jade.Boot
```

**Argumentos:**

```
-gui -agents  vendedor: examples.bookTrading.BookSellerAgent; comprador:  examples.bookTrading.BookBuyerAgent
```

Comment: O jade está rodando? `java -cp lib/jade.jar jade.Boot -gui -local-host 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Não sei informar, como disse sou iniciante e não sei muito a respeito... se puder me informar como verificar isso eu agradeceria muito.

Comment: Rode a linha de comando acima da pasta do jade (mais informações: http://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/JADEAdmin/startJade.html). Se funcionar tente o mesmo com o seu agente (repare no `-local-host` que você não colocou nos seus argumentos)